# numpy: How do I pick rows from two 2D arrays based on conditions in 1D arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two arrays of length `n`, namely `old_fitness` and `new_fitness`, and two matrices of dimension `nxm`, namely `old_values` and `new_values`.

What is the best way to create an `nxm` matrix `best_fitness` that comprises row `new_values[i]` when `new_fitness[i] > old_fitness[i]` and `old_values[i]` otherwise?

Something like:

```
best_values = nd.where(new_fitness > old_fitness, new_values, old_values)
```

but that works on rows of the last two matrices, instead of individual elements? I'm sure there's an easy answer, but I am a complete newbie to numpy.

Edit: `new_values` and `old_values` contain rows that represent possible solutions to a problem, and `new_fitness` and `old_fitness` contain a numeric measure of fitness for each possible solution / row in `new_values` and `old_values` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work as long as the comparison is of shape (n,1) - not (n,)

import numpy as np

```
old_fitness = np.asarray([0,1])
new_fitness = np.asarray([1,0])

old_value = np.asarray([[1,2], [3,4]])
new_value = np.asarray([[5,6], [7,8]])

np.where((new_fitness>old_fitness).reshape(old_fitness.shape[0],1), new_value, old_value)
```

returns

```
array([[5, 6],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. It didn't even occur to me to reshape the comparison array.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, working on numpy arrays:

```
best_values = numpy.copy(old_values)
best_values[new_fitness > old_fitness, :] = new_values[new_fitness > old_fitness, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the arrays of equal length? If so zip them and then use a map function to return the desired output.

For example, something like:

```
bests = map(new_val if new_val > old_val else old_val for (old_val, new_val) in zip(old_fitness, new_fitness))
```

Edit: this is probably better

```
bests = map(lambda n, o: n if n > o else o, new_fitness, old_fitness)
```

Here's another one that works too!

```
bests = [np.max(pair) for pair in zip(new_fitness, old_fitness)]
```

Comment: They are of equal length, so that's definitely one possibility, but I was hoping instead of list comprehensions / map, there was a numpy technique that would be more efficient.

Comment: I think I would have to do:

`best_values = [nv if nf > of else ov for nf, nv, of, ov in zip(new_fitness, new_values, old_fitness, old_values)]`

Comment: I'll clarify the question slightly.

Comment: I don't think that there would be a specific function for merging two lists an only preserving the max value at like indexes. It's too specific and easily achievable with a simple function. Let me know though if you find something!

Comment: Patol75 provided the perfect answer above. Check it out.
(BTW, nice first name :D.)